# Dllhost.exe*32 is unable to release 32-bit resources during uninstallation on a 64 bit machine

Tags: wix, windows-server-2008, 32bit-64bit, uninstallation, wix3

I am installing 32 bit application, in compatibility mode, on Windows 2008 R2 Server i.e. a 64-bit O.S. 
The Installation and the Functionality is working fine.

But, when trying to uninstall the application, we are receiving a error related to ‘COM Surrogate’. This error occurs randomly.

A message box is displayed saying “Close the below applications before uninstallation” and it displays the “COM Surrogate (Process ID)”. The ProcessID displayed is of the dllhost.exe*32 process. This is the special dllhost.exe, launched in 64-bit OS to support the 32-bit applications in compatibility mode. The 32-bit binaries required for the application are hosted by this exe. The life of this exe is only when any of the 32-bit application is running on a 64-bit machine.

Ideally, during uninstallation, dllhost.exe*32 should die gracefully and the uninstallation should be smooth. But, this is not happening some times.

If I wait for sometime or kill the dllhost.exe*32 manually then uninstallation works fine.

What I am looking at is the exact cause why the dllhost.exe*32 is not able to die gracefully and the resolution to it.

Please, if anyone could help us in this regard.

Comment: This question's offtopic, better asking on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the uninstallation procedure does not even ask the process to terminate, because there is no universal procedure to do so. Instead, it expects the application not be running when the uninstallation starts.

As it is apparently a COM object that is being served, you should find out what (other) application process is using the COM object, and make that process terminate. As a more brute-force approach: replace the COM dll with a proper application (COM server process), and arrange that application to provide an API to terminate it.